# reading formulated value from excel using oledb

Tags: .net, excel, c#-4.0, oledb

I am using C#.net (4.0) and trying to calculate some result by putting my parameters in an excel file. This exceil file as got the required formula in place. For example, when I enter my parameters in cells A1, A2 and A3, the result value is calculated and displayed in cell a4. The cell a4 is having a formula which utilises values from a1, a2 and a3.

I could connect to this excel file easily using oledb provider (v4.0) Then I could also set the cell values of a1, a2 and a3. The result was appearing in cell a4 (i opened the excel file to check). But the only prolem is when I read the value from cell a4, it is not returned as is.

The value calculated in a4 : 6.67%
The value I get in .net code of the same cell: 0.092323323211... (something like this)

As a solution, I tried to copy the "value" part of a3 in other cell (like b3 = VALUE(a3)) and tried to read b3. But I get same result.

Is there any fix for this ? Am I missing somethig here specific to formulated cells? or is it a bug of MS oledb?

Thanks for any inputs....

Answer (score 1):

Try adding IMEX=1 to your connection string.